# arch linux booting stops on [ ok ] Started Accounts Service

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, gnome

When I'm trying to start my archlinux system I see following image:

```
[ ok ] …
[ ok ] …
.
.
.
[ ok ] Started Authorization Manager.
[ ok ] Started Accounts Service.
```

and now system freezes. Gnome desktop environment does not start (although the [ok] list contains "Started GNOME Display Manager").

I decided to do one more test. I switched to the console by pressing ALT + F2 and opened a folder with my programs that use the graphic mode. First, I started the one that uses graphics.h. In the upper left corner a program window with a picture has appeared. Then I tried to start the game that uses X11. It crashed on a call to XOpenDisplay(NULL) with the error "memory protection violation".

I consider that it is the problem with X11 but I do not know how to fix it.

I will add that I have this problem after I tried to restore the system from "backup", which consisted in the fact that I copied the directories / usr / var / home / root / opt and partially etc with which I had a problem because on the one hand I did not want to destroy files / etc / fstab and / etc / mkinitcpio on the other hand, however, I wanted to restore files of various programs like gimp or locale.conf. So this can also be a configuration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be permissions in /bin/ are not correct.
Try reinstalling gdm gnome gnome-extra dbus xf86-video-intel or other video drivers you use by chrooting

Comment: gnome reinstallation fixed it